# jQuery ajax error not called when server is offline

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I am loading some data from the server with jquery.ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (data) {
            showData(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            showErrorDetails(e);
        }
    });
```

When the server is offline or the client has simply no connection to the network I would expect the error function to be executed - which works in Chrome - but when I test it in IE9 the error function never executes.

**update:**

myurl has for example the following value: "GetPlants?x=43.49&y=54.78&x2=60.50&y2=-12.43&zl=3"

It's the same domain (no subdomain).
On the serverside I am using ASP.net MVC 3, although that shouldn't matter, because the error function should be executed when server can't be reached.

**update 2:**
the success function isn't called either if the server is offline (if that helps)

**update 3:**

I think I found the issue. I set the src if some image elements on the page and when the connection to the server is lost and some images are not loaded yet then in some cases the error function of ajax calls is not executed. I was not able to create a small example to recreate this issue, seems like there is another factor which influences this behaviour.

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request, aka JSONP?

Comment: no errors, no jsonp, it's very weird

Comment: What is `myurl`? Does it have the same subdomain, domain, protocol, and port as the current page?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that re-creates what you are doing, but works correctly in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/NaFTJ/ (make sure your console is open, F12)

Comment: Yes, that also shows an error in my IE9, but it also shows an error if I set delay to 1000 (and timeout 10000); shouldn't it work in this case? It works if I remove delay completely.

Comment: You're right, i've got something wrong in the data i'm sending to jsfiddle.